# How to insert tabs inside ion content in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic-view

Always using the awesome framework Ionic for developing my mobile application. everything seems to work fine.

I want to add something particular to my app. I want to have tabs inside a ion-content.

I'm using button bar tabs. I'm not sure if this is the right solution or no.

I want to also let you know that I'm using already tabs tool in my app, so in my app.js I do have some code for navigating tabs. So I don't know how I would be able to add another one for another page.

My code :

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/gpLxPR)

Here is what I want :

[image: Screenshot of what I want]

Here some of my code :

```
<body>
<div> 
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
     <button class="button button-clear button-positive" href="index.html">Retour</button>

      <h1 class="title">Détails</h1>

    </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>

  <div class="item item-divider" style="height:45px">
      <div style="display:inline-block;  left:10px; position:absolute;">
   <h5>Competiton</h5>
   <h5>14th journey</h5>
          </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;  right:10px; position:absolute;">
   <h5>25 MAI 2015</h5>
            <h5>18:00</h5>
          </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="height:100px">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6a/Zte_Football_Club_Logo_90.png" style="width:55px; height:55px; position:absolute; left:10px; top:12px">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6a/Zte_Football_Club_Logo_90.png" style="width:55px; height:55px; position:absolute; right:10px; top:12px" >
      <h4 style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:70px">ASROME</h4> <h4 style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:70px">LAZIO</h4>
      <h4 style="position:absolute; left:150px; top:35px">3</h4> <h4 style="position:absolute; right:150px; top:35px">2</h4>
  </div>

<div class="button-bar">
<a class="button" tab-state ui-sref="home">Résumé</a>
  <a class="button" tab-state ui-sref="contact">Composition</a>

</div>

  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: hey did u get any solution?..

Comment: the question same with @Lakshay, did u get any solution ?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, I fixed it like this.

```
<ion-view view-title="Tabs">
    <ion-pane>
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-top">

            <!-- Tab 1 -->
            <ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/tab/tab1">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab1">
                    <ion-content>
                        Tab 1 content
                    </ion-content>

                </ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>


            <!-- Tab 2 -->
            <ion-tab title="Tab 2" href="#/tab/tab2">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab2">
                    <ion-content>
                        Tab 2 content
                    </ion-content>
                </ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>

    </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: You saved me from a lot of `<ion-pane>` ;)

Comment: @Gregoire Motot I have a doubt is it possible to put ion tabs into div tag so that i can make use of it just for half of my page to be tabs and others to be button like that any idea

Comment: Worked for me too, nice solution

Answer (score 8):

You should use a tab bar instead of a segmented control when you want to let the user move back and forth between distinct pages in your app.

For your solution you must use segments.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/

Comment: I delete my answer when I saw yours... That's the way :)

Answer (score 3):

As says Ionic documentation

> Note: do not place ion-tabs inside of an ion-content element; it has
>   been known to cause a certain CSS bug.

Comment: this is not an answer!

Comment: @BraianMellor I think it is. What OP wants does not fit into the paradigm of Ionic and the documentation says it clearly.

Comment: "we should find another way" is a comment. An answer is an answer for the problem, this just put a problem into the problem, an answer should be something like this https://codepen.io/leoz/pen/gpMMmW?editors=1010

Comment: @BraianMellor I deleted my comment because it can be misleading but the rest of my answer is correct. Question was "How to insert tabs inside ion content in Ionic", answer is "in no way, because documentation says do not place ion-tabs inside of an ion-content element".

Comment: And i think that's not a complete answer Olga. A complete answer should have a way to solve that, like the link I gave you. I understand what are you saying but that is not helping to solve the problem, that's just saying "that's not the way", so WHAT IS THE WAY??? that should be the answer ;) let me help you here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. And remember, we are here to help to solve problem